# Express - Uploading file through direct POST

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking to implement an API similar to Imgur's upload feature: http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#upload. In other words, a user should be able to upload an image by POSTing to `/upload` with an image file without using a form, ie through AJAX without setting the `Content-Type` header (just like Imgur). However, the only example I can find is the following: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/app.js

Question: How should I implement such an API? My concern is that Express won't interpret the command as `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the client sets the upload request's `Content-Type` properly (which it will if the form used for the upload has the correct `enctype` attribute) and you use `express.bodyParser()`, express will handle everything correctly.

Comment: sorry, i updated the question to be a little bit clearer. i don't want  to require the user to set `content-type` since it is not very useable.

Comment: How do you propose to accomplish this? If the `enctype` on the `<form>` element isn't set, the browser isn't even going to correctly assemble the request (all it will do is send the filename, but not the file's contents).

Comment: i don't know, that's why i'm asking. imgur does it somehow, don't see why i can't.

Comment: Ah, now I see that you aren't necessarily dealing with a request from a browser. Still, if the request is going to be directly programmed, that's all the more reason to set the headers correctly. If you really want to accept a request with malformed headers, you'll need to cobble up your own version of `bodyParser` (express actually uses `connect.bodyParser` which in turn uses `connect.multipart` which in turn uses `Formidable`). Note, though, that you may very well run into encoding issues.